# URDF Revolute Joints?

Tags: robotic-arm, ros, joint, urdf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

0
down vote
favorite

I'm having a hard time defining simple revolute joints in an arm. The arm is modeled in a stowed configuration, and 1-6  0
down vote
favorite

I'm having a hard time defining simple revolute joints in an arm. The arm is modeled in a stowed configuration, and 1-6 should rotate about their axes (along the center of the cylinder). When I try to control these joints in Rviz, the links do not rotate at all how I'm expecting/intending. This is my first time making a URDF file so your patience and help is appreciated. The links in the image are:

1. origin_joint (center of this box is also the global origin)
2. driven_1
3. driving_2
4. driven_2
5. driving_3
6. driven_3

[image: image description]

```
<robot name="bca_arm">

<!-- * * * Link Definitions * * * -->

<link name="origin_joint">
    <visual>
        <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
        <geometry>
            <box size="3.5 3 4.5"/>
        </geometry>
        <material name="Cyan1">
            <color rgba="0 0.9 0.9 1.0"/>
        </material>
    </visual>   
</link>

<link name="motor_1">
    <visual>
        <origin xyz="0 0 4.819" rpy="0 0 0"/>
        <geometry>
            <cylinder radius="1.1" length="5.138"/>
        </geometry>
        <material name="Yellow2">
            <color rgba="0.8 0.8 0 1.0"/>
        </material>
    </visual>   
</link>

<link name="origin_link">
    <visual>
        <origin xyz="0 0 -2.727" rpy="0 0 0"/>
        <geometry>
            <cylinder radius=".75" length=".954"/>
        </geometry>
        <material name="Yellow2">
            <color rgba="0.8 0.8 0 1.0"/>
        </material>
    </visual>   
</link>

<link name="driving_1">
    <visual>
        <origin xyz="0 0 -5.354" rpy="0 1.57 0"/>
        <geometry>
            <cylinder radius="2.15" length="3"/>
        </geometry>
        <material name="Cyan1">
            <color rgba="0 0.9 0.9 1.0"/>
        </material>
    </visual>   
</link>

<link name="motor_2">
    <visual>
        <origin xyz="2.9 0 -5.354" rpy="0 1.57 0"/>
        <geometry>
            <cylinder radius="1.1" length="2.814"/>
        </geometry>
        <material name="Yellow2">
            <color rgba="0.8 0.8 0 1.0"/>
        </material>
    </visual>   
</link>

<link name="driven_1">
    <visual>
        <origin xyz="-2.836 0 -5.354" rpy="0 1.57 0"/>
        <geometry>
            <cylinder radius="2.106" length="2.672"/>
        </geometry>
        <material name="Blue2">
            <color rgba="0 0 0.7 1.0"/>
        </material>
    </visual>   
</link>

<link name="rod_1">
    <visual>
        <origin xyz="-2.836 0 1.9" rpy="0 0 0"/>
        <geometry>
            <cylinder radius=".75" length="10.3"/>
        </geometry>
        <material name="Yellow2">
            <color rgba="0.8 0.8 0 1.0"/>
        </material>
    </visual>   
</link>

<link name="driving_2">
    <visual>
        <origin xyz="-2.836 0 9.054" rpy="0 1.57 0"/>
        <geometry>
            <cylinder radius="2.15" length="3"/>
        </geometry>
        <material name="Cyan1">
            <color rgba="0 0.9 0.9 1.0"/>
        </material>
    </visual>   
</link>

<link name="motor_3">
    <visual>
        <origin xyz="0 0 9.054" rpy="0 1.57 0"/>
        <geometry>
            <cylinder radius="1.1" length="2.814"/>
        </geometry>
        <material name="Yellow2">
            <color rgba="0.8 0.8 0 1.0"/>
        </material>
    </visual>   
</link>

<link name="driven_2">
    <visual>
        <origin xyz="-5.7 0 9.054" rpy="0 0 0"/>
        <geometry>
            <cylinder radius="1.37" length="4.5"/>
        </geometry>
        <material name="Blue2">
            <color rgba="0 0 0.7 1.0"/>
        </material>
    </visual>   
</link>

<link name="motor_4">
    <visual>
        <origin xyz="-5.7 0 13" rpy="0 0 0"/>
        <geometry>
            <cylinder radius=".825" length="3.5"/>
        </geometry>
        <material name="Yellow2">
            <color rgba="0.8 0.8 0 1.0"/>
        </material>
    </visual>   
</link>

<link name="rod_2">
    <visual>
        <origin xyz="-5.7 0 3.15" rpy="0 0 0"/>
        <geometry>
            <cylinder radius=".75" length="7.285"/>
        </geometry>
        <material name="Yellow2">
            <color rgba="0.8 0.8 0 1.0"/>
        </material>
    </visual>   
</link>

<link name="driving_3">
    <visual>
        <origin xyz="-5.7 0 -2.3" rpy="1.57 0 0"/>
        <geometry>
            <cylinder radius="2" length="3"/>
        </geometry>
        <material name="Cyan1">
            <color rgba="0 0.9 0.9 1.0"/>
        </material>
    </visual>   
</link>

<link name="motor_5">
    <visual>
        <origin xyz="-5.7 2 -2.3" rpy="1.57 0 0"/>
        <geometry>
            <cylinder radius=".825" length="1.161"/>
        </geometry>
        <material name="Yellow2">
            <color rgba="0.8 0.8 0 1.0"/>
        </material>
    </visual>   
</link>

<link name="driven_3">
    <visual>
        <origin xyz="-5.7 -2.8 -2.3" rpy="0 0 0"/>
        <geometry>
            <cylinder radius="1.37" length="4.5"/>
        </geometry>
        <material name="Blue2">
            <color rgba="0 0 0.7 1.0"/>
        </material>
    </visual>   
</link>

<link name="motor_6">
    <visual>
        <origin xyz="-5.7 -2.8 1.6" rpy="0 0 0"/>
        <geometry>
            <cylinder radius=".825" length="3.481"/>
        </geometry>
        <material name="Yellow2">
            <color rgba="0.8 0.8 0 1.0"/>
        </material>
    </visual>   
</link>

<!-- * * * Joint Definitions * * * -->

    <joint name="joint_1" type="fixed">
    <parent link="motor_1"/>
    <child link="origin_joint"/>
    <origin xyz="0 0 0"/>
</joint>

<joint name="joint_2" type="revolute">
    <parent link="origin_joint"/>
    <child link="origin_link"/>
    <origin xyz="0 0 -2.25" rpy="0 0 0"/>
    <axis xyz="0 0 1"/>
</joint>

<joint name="joint_3" type="fixed">
    <parent link="origin_link"/>
    <child link="driving_1"/>
    <origin xyz="0 0 0"/>
</joint>

<joint name="joint_4" type="fixed">
    <parent link="motor_2"/>
    <child link="driving_1"/>
    <origin xyz="0 0 0"/>
</joint>
    
<joint name="joint_5" type="revolute">
    <parent link="driving_1"/>
    <child link="driven_1"/>
    <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
    <axis xyz="1 0 0"/>
</joint>

<joint name="joint_6" type="fixed">
    <parent link="driven_1"/>
    <child link="rod_1"/>
    <origin xyz="0 0 0"/>
</joint>

<joint name="joint_7" type="fixed">
    <parent link="rod_1"/>
    <child link="driving_2"/>
    <origin xyz="0 0 0"/>
</joint>

<joint name="joint_8" type="fixed">
    <parent link="motor_3"/>
    <child link="driving_2"/>
    <origin xyz="0 0 0"/>
</joint>

<joint name="joint_9" type="revolute">
    <parent link="driving_2"/>
    <child link="driven_2"/>
    <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
    <axis xyz="1 0 0"/>
</joint>

<joint name="joint_10" type="fixed">
    <parent link="motor_4"/>
    <child link="driven_2"/>
    <origin xyz="0 0 0"/>
</joint>

<joint name="joint_11" type="revolute">
    <parent link="driven_2"/>
    <child link="rod_2"/>
    <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
    <axis xyz="0 0 1"/>
</joint>

<joint name="joint_12" type="fixed">
    <parent link="rod_2"/>
    <child link="driving_3"/>
    <origin xyz="0 0 0"/>
</joint>

<joint name="joint_13" type="fixed">
    <parent link="motor_5"/>
    <child link="driving_3"/>
    <origin xyz="0 0 0"/>
</joint>

<joint name="joint_14" type="revolute">
    <parent link="driving_3"/>
    <child link="driven_3"/>
    <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
    <axis xyz="1 0 0"/>
</joint>

<joint name="joint_15" type="fixed">
    <parent link="driven_3"/>
    <child link="motor_6"/>
    <origin xyz="0 0 0"/>
</joint>

</robot>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/273403/urdf-revolute-joints?/) by [fusionice](https://answers.ros.org/users/32302/fusionice/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2017-10-18

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-10-18**:\

> the links do not rotate at all how I'm expecting/intending.

If you say this, it would be good to tell us how you think it *should* rotate.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-10-18**:
I'm willing to look at this, but non of the `revolute` joints specify any `limit`s. That is not allowed, so the urdf you included will not load.

---

After adding some arbitrary limits:

```
Failed to find root link: Two root links found: [motor_1] and [motor_2]
```

**Comment by [fusionice](https://answers.ros.org/users/32302/fusionice/) on 2017-10-18**:
1-6 should rotate about their axes (along the center of the cylinder) and all portions of arm should remain connected

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-10-18**:
I have a suspicion you write "and all portions of the arm should remain connected" because they aren't right now. I think that is because you are specifying `geometry` with `origin`s different than your `joint`s. That can work, but you'll need to give `joint`s the corresponding `origin`s as well.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-10-18**:
I would recommend making all `geometry` `origin`s link-local, as the frames for your `joint`s. That will greatly simplify things.

In essence: make the `joint`s of all `link`s the `origin`s of the `link`s.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-10-18**:
Suggestion: check [wiki/urdf/xml](http://wiki.ros.org/urdf/XML) for the required elements and attributes.

Is the URDF you include in your question text the one you tested? Because I cannot get it to load at all without fixing it up. How did you determine that things don't work as you expect?

**Comment by [fusionice](https://answers.ros.org/users/32302/fusionice/) on 2017-10-18**:
Sorry all I was using this to work on and visualize what I was doing: https://mymodelrobot.appspot.com and realized Rviz wouldn't load it at all. I will try to redefine using joints/origins.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-10-18**:
Please also keep in mind that we use *metres* for everything in ROS, not millimetres. Right now your arm is several metres long and wide ..

**Comment by [fusionice](https://answers.ros.org/users/32302/fusionice/) on 2017-10-18**:
Thanks for the comments, had to make adjustments and it is now working properly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

```
<link name="base_link">
    <visual>
        <geometry>
            <box size="0.0889 0.0762 0.1143"/>
        </geometry>
    </visual>   
</link>


<link name="motor_1">
    <visual>
        <geometry>
            <cylinder radius="0.02794" length="0.1305"/>
        </geometry>
        <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
    </visual>   
</link>

<joint name="joint_1" type="fixed">
    <parent link="base_link"/>
    <child link="motor_1"/>
    <origin xyz="0 0 0.1224"/>
</joint>

<link name="origin_link">
    <visual>
        <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
        <geometry>
            <cylinder radius="0.01905" length="0.0242"/>
        </geometry>
        <material name="Yellow2">
            <color rgba="0.8 0.8 0 1.0"/>
        </material>
    </visual>   
</link>

<joint name="joint_2" type="revolute">
    <parent link="base_link"/>
    <child link="origin_link"/>
    <origin xyz="0 0 -0.0692" rpy="0 0 0"/>
    <limit lower="-3.1416" upper="3.1416" effort="10" velocity="3"/>
    <axis xyz="0 0 1"/>
</joint>

<link name="driving_1">
    <visual>
        <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 1.57 0"/>
        <geometry>
            <cylinder radius="0.05461" length="0.0762"/>
        </geometry>
        <material name="Cyan1">
            <color rgba="0 0.9 0.9 1.0"/>
        </material>
    </visual>   
</link>

<joint name="joint_3" type="fixed">
    <parent link="origin_link"/>
    <child link="driving_1"/>
    <origin xyz="0 0 -0.067"/>
</joint>

<link name="motor_2">
    <visual>
        <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 1.57 0"/>
        <geometry>
            <cylinder radius="0.02794" length="0.0715"/>
        </geometry>
        <material name="Yellow2">
            <color rgba="0.8 0.8 0 1.0"/>
        </material>
    </visual>   
</link>

<joint name="joint_4" type="fixed">
    <parent link="driving_1"/>
    <child link="motor_2"/>
    <origin xyz="0.074 0 0"/>
</joint>

<link name="driven_1">
    <visual>
        <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 1.57 0"/>
        <geometry>
            <cylinder radius="0.0535" length="0.068"/>
        </geometry>
        <material name="Blue2">
            <color rgba="0 0 0.7 1.0"/>
        </material>
    </visual>   
</link>

<joint name="joint_5" type="revolute">
    <parent link="driving_1"/>
    <child link="driven_1"/>
    <origin xyz="-0.0720 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
    <limit lower="-1.57" upper="1.57" effort="10" velocity="3"/>
    <axis xyz="1 0 0"/>
</joint>

<link name="rod_1">
    <visual>
        <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
        <geometry>
            <cylinder radius="0.019" length="0.262"/>
        </geometry>
        <material name="Yellow2">
            <color rgba="0.8 0.8 0 1.0"/>
        </material>
    </visual>   
</link>

<joint name="joint_6" type="fixed">
    <parent link="driven_1"/>
    <child link="rod_1"/>
    <origin xyz="0 0 0.18"/>
</joint>

<link name="driving_2">
    <visual>
        <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 1.57 0"/>
        <geometry>
            <cylinder radius="0.0546" length="0.0762"/>
        </geometry>
        <material name="Cyan1">
            <color rgba="0 0.9 0.9 1.0"/>
        </material>
    </visual>   
</link>

<joint name="joint_7" type="fixed">
    <parent link="rod_1"/>
    <child link="driving_2"/>
    <origin xyz="0 0 0.185"/>
</joint>

<link name="motor_3">
    <visual>
        <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 1.57 0"/>
        <geometry>
            <cylinder radius="0.02794" length="0.0715"/>
        </geometry>
        <material name="Yellow2">
            <color rgba="0.8 0.8 0 1.0"/>
        </material>
    </visual>   
</link>

<joint name="joint_8" type="fixed">
    <parent link="driving_2"/>
    <child link="motor_3"/>
    <origin xyz="0.074 0 0"/>
</joint>

<link name="driven_2">
    <visual>
        <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
        <geometry>
            <cylinder radius="0.035" length="0.1143"/>
        </geometry>
        <material name="Blue2">
            <color rgba="0 0 0.7 1.0"/>
        </material>
    </visual>   
</link>

<joint name="joint_9" type="revolute">
    <parent link="driving_2"/>
    <child link="driven_2"/>
    <origin xyz="-0.073 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
    <limit lower="-1.57" upper="1.57" effort="10" velocity="3"/>
    <axis xyz="1 0 0"/>
</joint>

<link name="motor_4">
    <visual>
        <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
        <geometry>
            <cylinder radius="0.021" length="0.0889"/>
        </geometry>
        <material name="Yellow2">
            <color rgba="0.8 0.8 0 1.0"/>
        </material>
    </visual>   
</link>

<joint name="joint_10" type="fixed">
    <parent link="driven_2"/>
    <child link="motor_4"/>
    <origin xyz="0 0 0.1016"/>
</joint>

<link name="rod_2">
    <visual>
        <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
        <geometry>
            <cylinder radius="0.019" length="0.185"/>
        </geometry>
        <material name="Yellow2">
            <color rgba="0.8 0.8 0 1.0"/>
        </material>
    </visual>   
</link>

<joint name="joint_11" type="revolute">
    <parent link="driven_2"/>
    <child link="rod_2"/>
    <origin xyz="0 0 -0.1496" rpy="0 0 0"/>
    <limit lower="-1.57" upper="1.57" effort="10" velocity="3"/>
    <axis xyz="0 0 1"/>
</joint>

<link name="driving_3">
    <visual>
        <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="1.57 0 0"/>
        <geometry>
            <cylinder radius="0.0508" length="0.0762"/>
        </geometry>
        <material name="Cyan1">
            <color rgba="0 0.9 0.9 1.0"/>
        </material>
    </visual>   
</link>

<joint name="joint_12" type="fixed">
    <parent link="rod_2"/>
    <child link="driving_3"/>
    <origin xyz="0 0 -0.1396"/>
</joint>

<link name="motor_5">
    <visual>
        <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="1.57 0 0"/>
        <geometry>
            <cylinder radius="0.0209" length="0.0294"/>
        </geometry>
        <material name="Yellow2">
            <color rgba="0.8 0.8 0 1.0"/>
        </material>
    </visual>   
</link>

<joint name="joint_13" type="fixed">
    <parent link="driving_3"/>
    <child link="motor_5"/>
    <origin xyz="0 0.0528 0"/>
</joint>

<link name="driven_3">
    <visual>
        <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
        <geometry>
            <cylinder radius="0.0347" length="0.1143"/>
        </geometry>
        <material name="Blue2">
            <color rgba="0 0 0.7 1.0"/>
        </material>
    </visual>   
</link>

<joint name="joint_14" type="revolute">
    <parent link="driving_3"/>
    <child link="driven_3"/>
    <origin xyz="0 -0.0729 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
    <limit lower="-1.57" upper="1.57" effort="10" velocity="3"/>
    <axis xyz="0 1 0"/>
</joint>

<link name="motor_6">
    <visual>
        <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
        <geometry>
            <cylinder radius="0.0209" length="0.0884"/>
        </geometry>
        <material name="Yellow2">
            <color rgba="0.8 0.8 0 1.0"/>
        </material>
    </visual>   
</link>

<joint name="joint_15" type="fixed">
    <parent link="driven_3"/>
    <child link="motor_6"/>
    <origin xyz="0 0 0.1016"/>
</joint>
```

---

Originally posted by [fusionice](https://answers.ros.org/users/32302/fusionice/) with karma: 16 on 2017-10-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [atom](https://answers.ros.org/users/30003/atom/) on 2022-10-13**:
Can you please tell me, what changes you made for this i have a similar problem, my robot's revolute joint isn't turning about its axis my question is here  https://answers.ros.org/question/407840/help-on-revolute-joint-placement-in-gazebo/

**Comment by [fusionice](https://answers.ros.org/users/32302/fusionice/) on 2022-10-14**:
Hi @atom. I haven't worked on this in quite some time but remember this online tool being very helpful in properly creating my URDF model. http://www.mymodelrobot.appspot.com/5629499534213120

**Comment by [atom](https://answers.ros.org/users/30003/atom/) on 2022-10-14**:
I've been using this website for designing the robot, but I think I'm not having a conceptual understanding of how to make a robot's revolute joining move around itself. Thank you for taking time to respond though, very much appreciated.. I've been stuck with this problem for more than 4 days now haha..